# How to set the first few characters of a WinForms TextBox to Read-Only?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a textbox on it that is used to enter a URL.  I need to add (http://) as a predefined value to this textbox and want it to be read only so the user won't be able to remove the http:// but he can write after it.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to simply put the "http://" in a label before the textbox.

Comment: Put another text box next to it and make that read only, but put them togther so it looks like its one. Then join the strings in the code?

Comment: i know that but for some reason i want to use it like this !

Comment: bind a keypress event; test length of the textfield; if <= 7, return false to the key event and so it will ignore the backspace event.

Comment: @Ismael, that won't work.  They could type a bunch of text and then change the http:// part without your code firing because it would be longer than 7.

Comment: @Ismael That doesnt stop you changing the `http://` as long as its over 7 characters.

Comment: It is impossible to make part of a textbox read only unfortunately.

Comment: @Doomsknight now i agree with you. but you can handle this in javascript to always force http:// as the first chars, just some IFs.

Comment: please confirm this is a winforms application, you seem to have confused a few of the posters

Comment: @musefan - It doesn't matter if its a desktop or web application the advice would be the same.  My advice is to allow them to delete anything they want.  When the focus leaves the textbox just attached the `http://` to the string.

Comment: @Ramhound: It does matter when there are some people posting with html code in an attempt to answer. And even a theory based answer would need to take into account what functions/events are actually available

Comment: I would recommend using a placeholder that says **http://** and then do sanity checking and prepend http:// if it doesn't exist.  A lot of modern browsers include the protocol when copying the URL, so your method may not be as fluid as you've thought it to be.

Comment: The problem with using a separate text field or label is that the user won’t be able to paste an URL into the text field without ending up with `http://http://`…

Comment: Are you totally sure that the URL entered could not start with another scheme? E.g. "https://"

Comment: This is important, as it denies a change in protocol, and ignores relative URLs.

Comment: You could fake it out by defining mouseDown should go to position 7 in the field.  left arrow key nav shouldn't let you go left of position 7.  Etc.

Comment: Another system I see on quite a few sites is where they have "http://" in the textbox, when you click on it disapears (a placeholder), signaling that the user doesn't need to type it. But this approach doesn't seem very user-friendly.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. The easy way is to just create a [label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) outside the text box (to the left) with those characters. (simple and easy to understand for the user)
2. Create a second readonly text box to use at the start, style it to match the input one and align them next to each other. Yes, you will get a single pixel line to split them both, but I think this will add to the user experience to make it obvious this is not for messing with (I would personally choose this option)
3. If you need the style you can [roll your own user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that uses a panel, label and textbox with appropriate border styling set as needed. (best way to get the exact style you need)
4. The fourth, more annoying way, would be to handle one of the key events (such as [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)) on the textbox itself. With this you can do numerous checks and alter the caret position to make it work, but trust me this will do your head in trying to get it working perfectly! (way too much hard work to get right)

To summarise, I think **option 2** is the best here. Of course if you were using WPF you would undoubtedly have a lot more flexibility in styling.

Comment: Option 5: Implicitely add the `http://` if it’s missing, just like a browser does. So when I enter `stackoverflow.com` and the text box loses the focus, change it to `http://stackoverflow.com`. If it already starts with `http://` leave it there, or even accept more than just `http` as the protocol.

Comment: Don't forget to give `https://` some love too.... and although rarer today, `ftp:` still has its place.

Comment: Option 4 is commonplace in JavaScript for similar format-locking techniques.

Comment: @poke: Pardon my correctness obsession, but I think `http` is a scheme in the URL. A scheme that refers to a protocol. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

Have you considered placing a label beside it with "http://" as the text? and then when accepting the users input you can just append the "http://" with your textbox.Text.

Here is another idea:

On every backspace press, count the number of characters in your textbox. If it is == 7, then ignore the backspace.  If it is greater, then check the number of characters after the backspace. If the number of characters is less than 7, clear the textbox and reset the text.

```
private void a_keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)8)
    {
        if (myTextbox.Text.Length == 7)
        // do stuff..
    }
    else if //do stuff...
}
```

Comment: backspace option is some nice out the box thinking, but don't forget pasting and select all issues.

Comment: well if the text is greater than 7, you can check if the text starts with http:\\, if so, leave it, if not, add it.  And I think that covers every possibility.

Comment: cant think of anything to argue with that at the moment ;)

Comment: You will have to check every possibility. If I only remove the 'h' it will not begin with "http:\\" but if you add it without removing "ttp:\\" you will get "http:\\ttp:\\\*something*.

Comment: Well, trolling user :P makes life harder for all of us. 

You could search for :\\ atleast, because you know that it won't appear anywhere else in the URL. Therefore, it makes it a lot easier to search and fix the URL, if this occured.

Comment: is keypress fired if I use a mouse to select and cut the text?

Comment: Nope :P so I guess that would be the hole. I'm sure there is an event of some kind for capturing that kind of action :S not really sure haha. Combine that with an OnTextChanged, or disable paste/cut all together? :P

Comment: what if you enter for example http://www.stackoverflow.com and mark the h of http and delete it...

Answer (score 12):

You could also not even display the http:// and just append it to the Textbox.Text code.  Check first that it doesn't start with that as well.

To clarify my last remark:

```
string sURL = txtURL.Text.StartsWith("http://") ? txtURL.Text : "http://" + txtURL.Text;
```

Comment: I assume he is wanting to display it in the textbox, hence why he doesn't want the label idea.

Comment: I agree to a point, but without further clarification from the OP as to what he's trying to accomplish and why, the best we can do is throw out some suggestions.

My point is to maintain the http:// in the value of what is being retrieved from the Textbox.Text value.  If the http:// is being maintained in the box for simply aesthetic purposes, then a lot more effort is needed.

Comment: Whats to stop them then typing in `http://` and causing an append to `http://http://blahblah`. Obvious solution to check before appending. +1 though as I dont think it was suggested by anyone else, but a valid idea. He does go around the idea of a read-only section. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;

    if (!textBox.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        textBox.Text = "http://";
        textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: That's closer to what he's looking for, but then if they type a whole URL and then go back and change the beginning, it will all get wiped out.

Comment: The text is still deletable though.

Comment: 10% towards a hack... try with KeyDown to bump it up to 25% completion ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a RichTextBox instead, it allows protecting text:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox1.Text = "http://";
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionProtected = true;
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        richTextBox1.DetectUrls = false;  // optional
    }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work well if you set its Multiline property to False.

A pragmatic way to do it with a TextBox is to just set it back the way you want it.  Also works with pastes and selection deletes:

```
    string protect = "http://";

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith(protect)) {
            textBox1.Text = protect;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice idea with the RTB, but the styling for this will conflict with other textbox styles :(

Answer (score 4):

**Note: I misread the question, due to somehow I was coming here from the "HTML"-tag. But if you want to do something like this with HTML/CSS, this could be one solution.**

You could do something like this:

```
<style>
    label.mylabel, input.myinput {
        display:        block;
        float:          left;
        height:         20px;
        margin:         0;
        padding:        10px 5px 0px 5px;
        border:         1px solid #ccc;
        font-size:      11px;
        line-height:    11px;
    }

    label.mylabel {
        border-right:   0;
    }

    input.myinput {
        border-left:    0;
    }
</style>

<label class="mylabel" for="myinput">http://</label>
<input id="myinput" class="myinput" name="myinput" value="">
```

So this has two advantages:

- it looks like one input box
- when the user hits "http", the actually form field will be focused

And of course, you have to add the 'http://' manually after sending in the form.

The whole thing has one disadvantage. What is, if your user wants to insert
'https://'? :)

Cheers,
Philipp

Comment: ...another disadvantage with your answer... the OP is not using HTML, this is a WinForms project

Comment: Oh man, I just realized it. Sorry, my mistake. I just hit the "HTML" tag in the overview and this one came up. Didn't read well enough. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted a CSS approach (coupled with a background image) you can try [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/S9yyJ/):

```
Enter URL: <input type="text" size="50" class="url" value="www.google.com" />

<style>
  input[type="text"].url {
    background: url(http://s18.postimage.org/4wkjdpidh/http.png) no-repeat left top transparent;
    text-indent: 34px;
  }
</style>
```

Then it's just a matter of prepending the `http://` back on the input's value when you go to process it.

Comment: It appears this is winforms; approach is still valid in-it-of-itself, however probably not for OP's problem. Still, I'll leave it here for SEO reference.

Answer (score 4):

As an option you can add an auto-size label to `TextBox` control. Also to force the text start after the label, you need to send `EM_SETMARGINS` to apply left padding to the text box:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class SampleTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int EM_SETMARGINS = 0xd3;
    private const int EC_LEFTMARGIN = 1;
    private Label label;
    public SampleTextBox() : base()
    {
        label = new Label() { Text = "http://", Dock = DockStyle.Left, AutoSize = true };
        this.Controls.Add(label);
    }
    public string Label
    {
        get { return label.Text; }
        set { label.Text = value; if (IsHandleCreated) SetMargin(); }
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetMargin();
    }
    private void SetMargin()
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, EC_LEFTMARGIN, label.Width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a label just left to the textboxt and set its text property to "http://". or you can append 2 textboxes one is read only the other is not read only. and write http:// in the one which is read only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate for the `keyup` event (and possibly others, e.g. Clipboard) and check the start of the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myField').bind('keypress', function(event)
{
    if (event.charCode == 0 && event.currentTarget.value.length <= 7)
{
     return false;
}
});
```

Comment: That won't work if.  If the string is longer than 7, they could still change the beginning.

Comment: @SteveDog: Actually, it wont work because winforms does not support javascript/JQuery

Comment: @musefan Well, yes, that's true too :)  Although, I don't believe the questioner ever said for sure it was a WinForm app.

Comment: @SteveDog: That group box styling with that default font is a dead give away, anybody who styles a html page like that should be shot!

Comment: @musefan fair enough, but it's still an honest mistake on Ismael's part, seeing as how Shikata didn't specify :)